# Merging sandbox to production - SFMC integration

Tags: marketing-cloud, sandbox, production, marketing-cloud-connect

We have integrated SFMC with our SIT SFDC sandbox. But what will happen with the integration when we merge to production? The integration is linked to the SFDC Org ID, so we assume that we will lose the connection, but is this the case? 
Does anybody have experience with Marketing Cloud Connector, that can shine some light on the merge from sandbox to production and how to handle that?

Answer (score 0):

It will stay integrated with the SIT sandbox. To have it connected to our prod environment, you would need to disconnect it from UAT and re aunthenticate. I would suggest having a separate business unit connected to your sandbox environment to avoid this

Comment: Sorry, for my late reply. Thank you for your reply. We have a business unit that we are only using for testing, so when we are moving to production we will also have the integration to a prod. BU. But have you felt it was necessary to redo a lot of testing after you integrated to your prod. environment?